# AngularFire2 4.0.0: Login with Email & Password

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Today I updated to AngularFire2 version 4. I'm struggling with the email and password login. Before I was using the following:

```
login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
    },
    {
        provider: AuthProviders.Password,
        method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Error
    })
}
```

It seems that login is not a method of the new `Auth`. It seems like the replacement is `singInWithEmailAndPassword()`. I've tried this:

```
login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
    },
    {
        provider: AuthProviders.Password,
        method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Error
    })
}
```

It doesn't match the call signature obviously, which is:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): firebase.Promise<any>
```

I'm not sure how I should do this.

Comment: Do you really need the provider and method ?

Comment: I don't. I think the method takes care of those, but getting rid of them still results in the parameter error.

Comment: You are giving the function an object instead of 2 variables.

Comment: Actually, you're totally correct! I did remove the curly braces, but I was keeping the property key value pairs. Not sure why I was doing that. If you put this in answer form I'll accept it.

Comment: I did it, glad to help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are importing 2 objects instead of the 2 required variables.

Correct the error by changing your code to this:

```
this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password);
```

OR

```
this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).catch(function(error){
  // Error Code
});
```